# SQL group_by syntax error

Tags: sql, sqlite, inner-join, join

I'm reasonably certain that this is a dumb question, but I've googled and searched Stackoverflow and still can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

I've got the following database schema:

#### guides

```
id
first_name
last_name
```

#### guides_trips

```
id
guide_id
trip_id
```

#### trips

```
id
name
```

I'm attempting to get a list of guides including a count of all of the trips that they are signed up for, with the eventual goal of being able to filter this count by trip criteria (hence the second join). Here's what I've got so far:

```
SELECT 
  guides.id,
  guides.first_name, 
  guides.last_name, 
  trips.name,
  guides_trips.trip_id,
  guides_trips.guide_id
FROM guides
  LEFT JOIN guides_trips ON guides.id = guides_trips.guide_id
  LEFT JOIN trips ON guides_trips.trip_id = trips.id
```

Which gives the following result

```
id          first_name  last_name   name             trip_id     guide_id  
----------  ----------  ----------  ---------------  ----------  ----------
1           Karelle     Ritchie     Mt. Erie Custom  2           1         
1           Karelle     Ritchie     Everest Base Ca  7           1         
1           Karelle     Ritchie     Mt. Baker        11          1         
1           Karelle     Ritchie     Washington Pass  28          1         
1           Karelle     Ritchie     Shuksan Custom   31          1         
1           Karelle     Ritchie     Shuksan          40          1         
1           Karelle     Ritchie     Shuksan          50          1         
1           Karelle     Ritchie     Mt. Baker Custo  70          1         
1           Karelle     Ritchie     Shuksan          73          1         
2           Genesis     Hoppe       Rainy Pass       13          2         
2           Genesis     Hoppe       Rainy Pass Cust  33          2         
2           Genesis     Hoppe       Shuksan          48          2         
2           Genesis     Hoppe       Rainy Pass       60          2         
3           Yolanda     Ziemann     Washington Pass  15          3         
3           Yolanda     Ziemann     Washington Pass  19          3
```

Here's what I'm *trying* to get working

```
SELECT 
  guides.id,
  guides.first_name, 
  guides.last_name, 
  trips.name,
  guides_trips.trip_id,
  guides_trips.guide_id,
  COUNT(trips.id) AS trips_count
FROM guides
  LEFT JOIN guides_trips ON guides.id = guides_trips.guide_id
  LEFT JOIN trips ON guides_trips.trip_id = trips.id
GROUP_BY guides.id;
```

regrettably, this gives me an `Error: near "GROUP_BY": syntax error`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: There's no underscore in `GROUP BY`

Comment: ...times when you wish you had a rubber duck. Thanks so much, I've apparently been writing way too many ActiveRecord queries lately!

Comment: Glad to have "quacked the case" (sorry). Sleep well! :)

Answer (score 2):

Reading the error to helps you figure out whats going on.. 'Syntax Error'. GROUP_BY should be 'GROUP BY'

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html

Answer (score 0):

as IMSOP said no _ in group by, but you also need to group by all the non aggregate selected values.

```
SELECT 
   guides.id,
   guides.first_name, 
   guides.last_name, 
   trips.name,
   guides_trips.trip_id,
   guides_trips.guide_id,
   COUNT(trips.id) AS trips_count
FROM guides
LEFT JOIN guides_trips ON guides.id = guides_trips.guide_id
LEFT JOIN trips ON guides_trips.trip_id = trips.id
GROUP BY 
   guides.id,
   guides.first_name, 
   guides.last_name, 
   trips.name,
   guides_trips.trip_id,
   guides_trips.guide_id
```